# char pointer to array conversions to char pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function:

```
void add(char const**);
```

And I invoke it as follow:

```
template<typename T>
void anotherAdd(T const& t) {
  add(&t);
}
...
anotherAdd("some string");
```

As a result I get the error:

```
 no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char (*)[10]' to 'const char**'
```

Why the conversion can't be made?

Because I think the following is true:

```
"some string" <=> char const* =>
&"some string" <=> char const**
```

Comment: Why have you made a template function that relies on a function that only works on a `char const **`? I you want this to work, you will have to cast `T const& t` to a `char const **`.

Comment: You will need to explain what you are actually trying to achieve, since what you are doing in the code doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Are you asking how to get your code to work, or are you asking why that conversion can't be made?

Comment: I removed my downvote, since you kind of salvaged your question with the last edit.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not pointers.

This code expects a **pointer to a pointer**

```
void add(char const**);
```

The compiler is telling you that it can't produce a **pointer to a pointer** because your code has no pointer to point to.  You're effectively trying to evaluate `&"some string"`, which has no valid meaning.

This code will work, because it creates the missing `char const*` that you're trying to take the address of.

```
template<typename T>
void anotherAdd(T const& t) {
  char const *pt = &t; // Now there's a pointer that you can take the address of.
  add(&pt);
}
```

Comment: And what is `&"some string"`? is not it `char const**`? Because `const char[]` is `const char *`.

Comment: @user14416 *"const char[] is const char *"*  No, it isn't.  Arrays are not pointers.  You're getting an error because you're assuming that if you have an array, you have a pointer variable somewhere.

Comment: Ok, the follwoing answer (http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10/) says that it is true.